# How to utilize mutex properly in this scenario

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've implemented Cam class that retrieves frames from a webcam. Cam class has its own thread for acquiring frames. The code is running smoothly. What I would like to do is to implement GUI Class that is capable of showing frames in an appropriate widget. The member data `m_frame` holds the current image and it should be accessible from two independent threads. My question is where should I utilize `mutex` to safely access the frame? Is it enough to use it at `getFrame()` as follows:

```
cv::Mat Cam::getFrame()
{ 
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx)
return m_frame;
}
```

Or at the point where the m_frame is modified in the independent thread as follows:

```
void Cam::getFrameFromCam()
{
    // Independent Thread 
    while( m_isCamThreadRunning ){
        if ( m_isCamOpen ){
             std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            // acquire frame 
            *cap >> m_frame;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In both methods (it is the same mutex in both right) as they need to be protected from each other.  Conciser using 2 frames and just flipping between them.

Comment: @RichardCritten, "it is the same mutex in both right" yes.

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing how exactly `m_frame` works I would suggest you to pass to `getFrame()` a reference to an object which can hold `m_frame` and you can safely - using `std::lock_guard` - copy it into the provided reference.

Something - abstract code - like this [I don't know anything regarding copying `cv::Math`]:

```
cv::Mat & Cam::getFrame( cv::Math & myCopyOfFrame )
{ 
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
   myCopyOfFrame = m_frame;
   return myCopyOfFrame;
}
```

Comment: Something like this `cv::Mat Cam::getFrame()
{ 
 std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
 cv::Mat temp = m_frame;
 return temp;
}
`

Comment: why there is undefined behaviour in OPs code? OP returns a `cv::Mat`, ie there is already a copy. When you return a reference it is of course different

Comment: @tobi303 I wrote I don't know how `m_frame` works. When the OP wants to protect the access to `m_frame` by a mutex then I my eyes there must be a reason why a concurrent access should be avoided and he is locking `m_frame` only in the function but then it is not locked anymore.

Comment: sry, dont understand, the caller of `getFrame` never has access to `m_frame`, because it already does return a copy in OPs code. And I dont see any undefined behaviour in OPs code

Comment: ....btw what is the point of returning the same reference that you pass in as parameter?

Comment: @tobi303 I wrote **abstract** code because I know its not working. The OP asked regarding mutex without providing any further information. My focus was how to solve it correctly using mutex.

Comment: sorry, but it have the impression we are talking about different things. My question is: What is wrong with OPs code? I dont see the problem. Why is there undefined behaviour? I dont see any